# Cerrar notificaciones al cerrar la aplicación

Tags: java, android-studio, push-notification, android-notifications

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación que me genera notificaciones al ocurrir ciertos eventos definidos por el proyecto. La cosa es que estas notificaciones deberían ser cerradas al cerrar totalmente la aplicación (`onDestroy()`).

```
@Override
protected  void onDestroy() {
    ...
    ...
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

, cosa que no hace.

¿Alguien sabe por qué ocurre esto? o alguna manera de lograr cerrarlas?

Comment: Creo que es lo que buscas, mira [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26507148)

Comment: Si tienes algún código dentro de onDestroy puedes agregarlo a tu pregunta, tal vez solo tienes un detalle pequeño.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando el `NotificationManager` que creo la notificación mediante el método [cancelAll()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancelAll()) puedes eliminar las notificaciones creadas.

> [cancelAll()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancelAll()) Cancelar todas las notificaciones mostradas
>   anteriormente.

Si deseas eliminar las notificaciones cuando se cierra tu aplicación puedes realizarlo dentro del método [onDestroy()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()) de tu activity principal.

```
@Override
protected  void onDestroy() {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = ((NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE));
    notificationManager.cancelAll();

    super.onDestroy();
}
```